# Bayes Theorem for Conditional Probability

Tags: probability-theory

Can we write the Bayes Theorem in the following form ?

P(A|B,C) $\alpha$  P(B|A,C)P(A|C)

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For equations, please refer to this [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

$$P(A|B,C) = \frac{P(A,B|C)}{P(B|C)} = \frac{P(B|A,C)P(A|C)}{P(B|C)}.$$

Comment: So can we add any number of random variables to the right hand side of the conditional equation ? like   P (A|B,C,D....Z) = P(A,B|C,D...Z)/ P(B|C,D,...Z) ?

Comment: Yes for sure, as long as they don't result in a denominator that depends on $A$, nothing weird will happen.